# How to avoid infinite recursion in search sdcard android app

Tags: java, android

```
public ArrayList<File> getFile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; ++i) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                getFile(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].toString().indexOf(edit) >= 0) {  
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList;
 }
```

Sometimes because of the file folder too much, resulting in flashback situation, how to solve this?

```
  root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath());
        getFile(root);
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); ++i) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(fileList.get(i).getName());
            textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); 
        view.addView(textView);
```

this is my textView